# Laravel hasOne through method using Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What I'm trying to achieve. I dealing with 4 tables:

1. branches (**id**(PK), **branch_name**)
2. staff (**id**(PK), **staff_name**)
3. branch_heads(**staff_id**(FK -staff),**branch_id**(FK -branch))

**Rules**

1. Staff belongs to a branch
2. branch has many staff
3. Each branch is managed by one staff

**Below is my code for Branch Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\CompanyStructure;

use App\Models\StaffManagement\Staff;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\CompanyStructure\BranchHead;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Branch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'branch_name',
    ];

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Staff::class);
    }

    public function branchhead()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(BranchHead::class);
    }
}
```

**Below is my code for Staff Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\StaffManagement;

use App\Models\CompanyStructure\Branch;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Staff extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'staff';
    protected $fillable = [
        'staff_name',
    ];

    public function branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Branch::class);
    }

}
```

**Below is my code for BranchHead Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\CompanyStructure;

use App\Models\StaffManagement\Staff;
use App\Models\CompanyStructure\Branch;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class BranchHead extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'staff_id',
        'branch_id',
    ];

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Staff::class);
    }

    public function branch()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Branch::class);
    }

}
```

results from tinker:

```
Branch::find(1)->branchhead -- gives me the results of the staff_id that manages a particular branch_id. But can't go beyond that level to get which staff_name that manages which branch.
```

I'm using Laravel 9 and PHP 8.1

How can I get the staff_names?

Comment: why is the branch head not just a flag on one staff ? you dont need a pivot table(many to many) for a one to one relation.

Comment: @N69S How do I achieve that, and also how do I display the staff name(Manager) on respective branches if i'm to fag within the staff table,  any kind of help is kindly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation between staff and branches is a one to many with a special staff entity that can be the branch head.

- branches (id(PK), branch_name)
- staff (id(PK), branch_id(FK -branch), staff_name, is_head_branch)

```
class Branch extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'branch_name',
    ];

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Staff::class);
    }

    public function branchhead()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(staff::class)->where('is_head_branch',1);
    }
}
```

Add in comment any issue you have with this structure. I'll edit in the response.

To get all staff from a branch use

```
$branch->staff
```

it will include the head branch staff member (you can check on the flag `$staffMember->is_head_branch == 1`)

To get all BranchHeads with their associated branch or the other way around, do it like this

```
$headBranchs = Staff::where('is_head_branch', 1)->with('branch')->get();
//or
$branchs = Branch::with('branchhead')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, @N69S, I've applied that solution but I now get this error: Attempt to read property "staff" on null, How can I display the results regardless of that error,  The error clears only if all the branches has Managers

Comment: @MasabaJamesMoses somewhere you are doing `$branch->branchhead->staff` and you dont need to do it. `$branch->branchhead` returns the staff member or null directly

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing... Kindly advise on the right way I should do it. Thanks

Comment: @MasabaJamesMoses added some pointers in the answer

Comment: Thanks, @N69S, I think I'm getting closer to the answer but I have a feeling I missing out on something..,  This one **$branchs = Branch::with('branchhead')->get();** works fine but it selects all staff that belong to each branch If I try to use **$headBranchs = Staff::where('is_head_branch', 1)->with('branch')->get();**  it gets me a list of staff who heads any branch. My requirement is to get all Branches with their heads, In case there is no head then the button for add will be availed else the button for the update will be availed. Sorry for bothering you. Thanks

Comment: To make it more clear, This one **$branches = Branch::with('branchhead')->get();** seems the right one I should use because it spools all staff for each branch if I use this: **$branch->staff**, But now what I need to be guided on it how to flag the column for staff to only bring the one that heads a branch. The reason I want to flag within the column is that if I do it globally I may miss out on the count() for staff that belongs to each branch. Also if I attempt to add: **$branch->staff->staff_name** I get this error: **Property [staff_name] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: @MasabaJamesMoses you use this one `$branches = Branch::with('branchhead')->get()` and get the branch head with `$branch->branchhead` not staff.

Comment: Good. It's working fine, Thanks for your tireless efforts so far,  Just one final step is to specify a particular column Name say staff_name because with this **$branch->branchhead** I'm getting the entire JSON response. I get this error: **Attempt to read property "first_name" on null** when I try to append the staff_name column like this **$branch->branchhead->staff_name**. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243563/discussion-between-masaba-james-moses-and-n69s).